# Bios update for Pegatron Corporation A15 motherboard

Tags: windows-8, motherboard, bios

I am fighting against a problem. The problem (short version) is that when I install Windows 8.1 on my laptop, when I restart it the screen is black. I already have a post regarding this problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/884210/my-laptops-screen-wont-turn-on-after-restart-but-it-will-after-shutdown).

The thing is that since then I thought of updating my BIOS which is really old (2010), so maybe the bug occurs because of that.

The problem is I cannot find anywhere the BIOS update and even worse, I cannot be sure if there even is a bios update.

Info:

```
Motherboard:
    Manufacturer: Pegatron Corporation
    Model: A15

BIOS:
    Brand: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 300
    Date: 12/22/2011
```

Is there a bios update for this product? And if yes, where can I find it?

Comment: Updating your BIOS will unlikely solve the problem you have.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: The last line of my question:
" Is there a bios update for this product? And if yes, where can I find it? "
I cannot find the update for my motherboard.

Comment: We are not a file location service.  `Pegatron Corporation` manufactured motherboards for other suppliers.  The simplest way would be to go to the OEM website for any BIOS updates.  I can with 99.99% certainty tell you that updating your BIOS firmware will not solve your problem though.  I found [this](http://www.technopat.net/forum/blogs/recep-baltas/516-casper-pegatron-a15-bios-guncelleme-rehberi.html) in reference to the A15

Comment: Yeah I have stumbled upon the same reference too but I am not sure if I can trust it. I am a bit scared regarding BIOS... If something goes wrong my laptop will be just a fancy brick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching I decided to trust [this link](https://www.technopat.net/sosyal/blog-i%C3%A7erik/casper-pegatron-a15-bios-g%C3%BCncelleme-rehberi.164/) (as Ramhound suggested) to update my bios.

A great help was [this little page over here](http://ftp.dns-shop.ru/Notebooks/A15HR/) !!!

Also, the problem solved. I don't have black screen anymore.

The problem is that the first link I gave you is in Turkish so you have to translate it. You could use Google Translate but to save you the time I will try to explain the critical points here:

1. Download HP Usb Disk Storage Format tool from here: www. technopat.net/2010/08/14/hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool-v2-2-3/
2. Download Windows 98 DOS files from [here](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=196).
3. Run the usb disk storage format tool and "Create a DOS startup disk, select the". **NOTE:** All items on your flash drive will be deleted. Make sure you don't have anything you want in there. You need to choose a FAT system.
4. After it's done you can try boot up your pc. You should see a Windows 98 command prompt and you on C:. If you run "dir" you will notice that C:\ is empty.
5. Return to your windows, and download BIOS update and update tool from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/c541o1b346q4iqn/Technopat.Pegatron.A15.BIOS.Update.rar).
6. While you are in Windows, plug your flash drive with win98. You should be able to open it normally. Unzip the folder of the BIOS update (you need WinRar 5+ to unrar it) and throw it in there.
7. Reboot your pc and when you are in Win98 console type dir. You should see your folder. Cd in it.
8. Run the bat (tp.bat) or just run "aflash3.exe A15PG.303".
9. Click 'y' on the prompt. It will ask you if you are sure you want to take your chances and proceed YOLO. Do it if you feel brave enough. Worked for me and I am positive it is going to work for you too.
10. Wait till it ends.
11. Restart your pc. Everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated an even  older Pegatron A15 from 210 to 303; it worked for me as well.

This was on Windows 10, upgraded from Windows 7 Pro.